# Turning string inside string into "normal" string

Tags: python, string

I have a routine which gives me a list which looks like :

```
["'foo'", "'bar'", "'tmp'", "'tmp2'" …]
```

How can I turn these into:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'tmp', 'tmp2']
```

in Python 2.7?

Comment: Use either `str.strip` or `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_list = [x[1:-1] for x in old_list]`

A simple list comprehension to recreate the list without the first and last character should do the trick.

Comment: One knows when its to late to work, when one is not able to solve such simple questions. Thanks for the answer though ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can strip the quotes:

```
lst = [entry[1:-1] for entry in lst]
```

or

```
lst = [entry.strip("'") for entry in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings have quote characters at the start and the end, and you want to strip them off, you could do this:

```
mylist = [s[1:-1] for s in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace single quotes with nothing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

badstrings=["'foo'", "'bar'", "'tmp'", "'tmp2'"]

goodstrings=[]

for badstring in badstrings:
    goodstring=badstring.replace("'", '')
    goodstrings.append(goodstring)

print goodstrings
```

Output

```
['foo', 'bar', 'tmp', 'tmp2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=["'foo'", "'bar'", "'tmp'", "'tmp2'"]
print [i.rstrip("'").lstrip("'") for i in x]
```

You should use `rstrip and lstrip` instead of just `strip` for the cases where `'` is present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using strip function we can strip the double codes and return the result with single codes values.

Print [ values.strip ("'") for values in question]